# R - Dataframe is setting an arbitrary max of 10?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a personal project to visualize some NBA data, and when sorting within the dataframe created from reading a csv file, it seems to set 10 as the max value for all categories ( such as points, FGA, etc). Does anyone know why/how to "uncap" this?

Ex: Steph Curry can be seen here with 3PA greater than 10.

However, `` max(stats$`3pa`) `` returns `9.2`, same thing occurs with other categories such as Points, where `max(stats$PTS)` returns `9.9`.

[image]

EDIT: dput(head(stats)):

```
> dput(head(stats))
structure(list(Player = c("Precious Achiuwa", "Steven Adams", 
"Bam Adebayo", "LaMarcus Aldridge", "Ty-Shon Alexander", "Nickeil Alexander-Walker"
), Pos = c("PF", "C", "C", "C", "SG", "SG"), Age = c("21", "27", 
"23", "35", "22", "22"), Tm = c("MIA", "NOP", "MIA", "TOT", "PHO", 
"NOP"), G = c("61", "58", "64", "26", "15", "46"), GS = c("4", 
"58", "64", "23", "0", "13"), MP = c("12.1", "27.7", "33.5", 
"25.9", "3.1", "21.9"), FG = c("2.0", "3.3", "7.1", "5.4", "0.2", 
"4.2"), FGA = c("3.7", "5.3", "12.5", "11.4", "0.8", "10.0"), 
    `FG%` = c(".544", ".614", ".570", ".473", ".250", ".419"), 
    `3P` = c("0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "1.2", "0.1", "1.7"), `3PA` = c("0.0", 
    "0.1", "0.1", "3.1", "0.6", "4.8"), `3P%` = c(".000", ".000", 
    ".250", ".388", ".222", ".347"), `2P` = c("2.0", "3.3", "7.1", 
    "4.2", "0.1", "2.5"), `2PA` = c("3.7", "5.3", "12.4", "8.3", 
    "0.2", "5.2"), `2P%` = c(".546", ".620", ".573", ".505", 
    ".333", ".485"), `eFG%` = c(".544", ".614", ".571", ".525", 
    ".333", ".502"), FT = c("0.9", "1.0", "4.4", "1.6", "0.1", 
    "1.0"), FTA = c("1.8", "2.3", "5.5", "1.8", "0.1", "1.4"), 
    `FT%` = c(".509", ".444", ".799", ".872", ".500", ".727"), 
    ORB = c("1.2", "3.7", "2.2", "0.7", "0.1", "0.3"), DRB = c("2.2", 
    "5.2", "6.7", "3.8", "0.5", "2.8"), TRB = c("3.4", "8.9", 
    "9.0", "4.5", "0.7", "3.1"), AST = c("0.5", "1.9", "5.4", 
    "1.9", "0.4", "2.2"), STL = c("0.3", "0.9", "1.2", "0.4", 
    "0.0", "1.0"), BLK = c("0.5", "0.7", "1.0", "1.1", "0.1", 
    "0.5"), TOV = c("0.7", "1.3", "2.6", "1.0", "0.2", "1.5"), 
    PF = c("1.5", "1.9", "2.3", "1.8", "0.1", "1.9"), PTS = c("5.0", 
    "7.6", "18.7", "13.5", "0.6", "11.0"), c(" ", " ", " ", " ", 
    " ", " ")), row.names = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT2: Update
as.numeric(max(stats$`3PA`)) seems to work, thank you all for bearing with my stupidity!

Comment: Please read the guidelines at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular questions must include complete reproducible code including all library statements and inputs so anyone else can run it and see the result themselves.  If it is large create a small example which illustrates the problem using less code and data but is still reproducible.

Comment: Please use ``dput(stats)`` rather than using images of data. Thank you.

Comment: The actual dataframe is quite large so I'm not sure dput(stats) would be super helpful unless I'm missing something, as I'm just a novice to this type of stuff!

Comment: Try dput(head(stats)), that should only return the first few rows.

Comment: The data type of every column in that data is character, if you want to use something like max you need to convert them to numeric data types. You can probably do that when you read the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was the vectors being read as strings rather than doubles, so the simple addition of as.numeric() seemed to fix it!

Comment: You should fix this when importing the data, not after it's been imported.

Comment: Is there a way to mark only certain columns as numeric when doing so?

Comment: How are you currently importing the data?